# Convert feet and inches to centimeters in Go?

Tags: go, type-conversion

I am new to Go and I am a bit stuck on a problem regarding human height conversion from feet/inches to cm.

How can I convert, in an efficient way, a string that looks like this `5'2''` to an centimeter int?

Edit: 
After some more testing I ended up with this solution. How can it be improved?

```
height := strings.Split("5'2''", "'")
heightfeet,err :=strconv.ParseFloat(height[0],10)
heightinch,err :=strconv.ParseFloat(height[1],10)
heightcm :=heightfeet*30.48+heightinch*2.54
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón I updated the question with a working solution. It can probably use some improvement though. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go, but depending on the order of operations it follows, remember that ((heightfeet*30.48) + (heightinch*2.54)) IS NOT the same as (heightfeet*30.48+heightinch*2.54).
 In fact, I believe your code will output 392.XX cm, which is about 12 feet.

Comment: @Astor139 The output is actually 157,48 so I think its OK like that. multiplication is calculated before addition?

Comment: @Kaah: A test case: `"2''"` or two inches.

Comment: @peterSO Yeah, that would ruin it. It would ruin AndreaM16 too it looks like. Maybe its abit outside the scope of my particular issue since the input is human heights. I will make that clear in the question. But I agree that it would be good practice to take care of such a case as well.

Comment: @Kaah: An obvious test case for you: `69.3''`. For statistical purposes, heights are measured in centimeters or inches. For example, the [US CDC says the average height](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/body-measurements.htm) for men is 69.3'' and for women 63.8''.

Comment: @Kaah: Floating point is an approximation. Minimize floating-point errors. For example, write `heightcm := (heightfeet*12 + heightinch) * 2.54`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like your approach is fine, but, if you actually want to be sure to extract only the integers and using constants take a look at this [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jdKHcZsLyh) I set up.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    //Defining our constants     
    const cm1 = 30.48       
    const cm2 =  2.54 

    //Slice to contain parsed ints
    var parsedTokens []float64

    feet := "5'2''"

    //Regex to extract only integers
    reg := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
    filtered:= reg.FindAllString(feet, -1)

    //Parse each value v in filtered and append it into parsedTokens
    for _, v := range filtered {
        k, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(v, 64)
        parsedTokens = append(parsedTokens, k)
    }

    //157.48000000000002
    fmt.Println(parsedTokens[0]*cm1 + parsedTokens[1]*cm2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing another way to do this. I agree with you, if that input format would change some day it could ruin my script.